# Laravel - Função no Controller

Tags: php, laravel-5

Estou com uma dúvida em relação ao Laravel e um projeto meu sendo essa a função que recebe as informações de um formulário na qual o administrador escolhe o evento e os `usuarios` (`multiple select`) para gerar o certificado (*armazenado na tabela* `certificados` - colunas `id` / `id_usuario` / `id_evento`)

```php
public function gerar(Request $request)
{
    $id_evento = $request->id_evento;
    $id_participantes = $request->input('participantes');   

    foreach ($id_participantes as $id)
    {
        if($this->existeCertificado($id, $id_evento))
        {
            $certificado = new Certificado();

            $certificado->id_evento = $request->id_evento;
            $certificado->qualidade = $request->qualidade;
            $certificado->id_usuario = $id;
            $certificado->save();
            $pusher = App::make('pusher');

            //default pusher notification.
            //by default channel=test-channel,event=test-event
            //Here is a pusher notification example when you create 
            //a new resource in storage.
            //you can modify anything you want or use it wherever.
            $pusher->trigger('test-channel',
                             'test-event',
                            ['message' => 'Certificado $evento->titulo_evento !!']);

            return redirect('certificado')->with('status', 'Certificados gerados!');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('certificado')
                       ->with('status', 'Erro ao gerar alguns certificados!');
        }            
     }
}
```

Essa é a função que busca no meu banco de dados se o usuário (`id_usuario`) já possui algum certificado no evento (`id_evento`):

```php
public function existeCertificado($id, $id_evento)
{
    $existeCert = DB::table('certificados')
             ->where([['id_usuario', $id], ['id_evento', $id_evento]])
             ->get();
    if($existeCert == NULL)
    {
        return TRUE;
    } 
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }        
}
```

Caso o usuário já tenha um certificado no mesmo evento, não é gerado outro se não tiver, é então gerado.

O problema é que de qualquer forma (se já houver registro do `usuario` no evento ou se não houver) o sistema cai no `else` (**erro ao gerar**).

Comment: A principio o codigo parece estar correto, ja tentou dar um dd() (var_dump do laravel) nas variaveis recebidas na função antes de fazer a consulta para verificar se estão com valores corretos ou vem vazios ou em forma de array?

Comment: Todas as vezes que dois ou mais partipantes forem escolhidos o seu código vai bugar ... !!! porque ele faz um foreach e executa um redirect ele não executa todo o for ... Você observou esse detalhe?

Answer (score -1):

O teu código está retornando sempre `TRUE` pelo fato de que o método `get()` do Eloquent retorna uma coleção e não um valor booleano. Ou seja, mesmo que não existam registros que satisfaçam a tua consulta o retorno vai ser sempre `TRUE`. Tu deves verificar se esta coleção está vazia ou não para que tua lógica faça sentido.

Comment: Nesses casos é melhor usar o `count()` no lugar do `get()`.

Comment: Concordo que o ideal seja usar o `count()`, mas minha resposta foi a explicação do PORQUE não está funcionando a lógica dele.

Comment: Com certeza, eu coloquei pra ajudar na resposta para o Gabriel e você pode até editar a sua resposta para colocar um exemplo usando o `count()`. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Creio que apenas com a inserção da função `firstOrNew` resolve o problema.

```
        $certificado = certificado::firstOrNew(['id_evento' => $request->id_evento]);
        $certificado->id_evento = $request->id_evento;
        $certificado->qualidade = $request->qualidade;
        $certificado->id_usuario = $id;
        $certificado->save();
        $pusher = App::make('pusher');
```

Comment: Alterei a resposta e retirei o link.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function existeCertificado($id, $id_evento)
{
    $existeCert = DB::table('certificados')
             ->where([['id_usuario', $id], ['id_evento', $id_evento]])
             ->first();

    if(is_null($existeCert))
    {
        return TRUE;
    } 
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }        
}
```

Se você substituir o get() por first() o laravel vai te retornar o valor encontrado, ou um null, caso não tenha.. só de uma olhadinha na doc, acho que pode ser mais interessante usar o Eloquent, do que o query builder assim nestes casaso, como está fazendo.

Também seria legal fazer a comparação usando a função is_null() php, que serve exatamente para informar se um valor é nulo ou não:

**is_null() php:** http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-null.php
**first() - Laravel:** https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

Answer (score -1):

Refatorei o seu código e consegui enxugar os 2 métodos em apenas 1, espero que te ajude.

```
public function gerar(Request $request)
{
    $fields = $request->all();

    foreach ($fields['participantes'] as $value) {
        $hasEvent = Certificado::where('id_usuario', $value)->where('id_evento', $fields['id_evento'])->first();
        if ($hasEvent) {
            return redirect('certificado')->with('status', 'Erro ao gerar alguns certificados!');
        }

        $certificado = Certificado::create($fields);
        $pusher = App::make('pusher');

        // Obs.: não sei de onde você tirou essa variavel $evento pq no seu código não tem ela instanciada
        $pusher->trigger('test-channel',
                             'test-event',
                            ['message' => "Certificado {$evento->titulo_evento} !!"]); 

        return redirect('certificado')->with('status', 'Certificados gerados!');
    }
}
```